# WPF drag drop between two different Windows

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, drag-and-drop

does anyone know how to make a drag and drop between two different wpf windows ?
In Window1 a detect drag action,

```
 void textBoxName_IsMouseCapturedChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((bool)e.NewValue == false)
            return;

        DataObject dataObj = null;

        DragDropInAction = true;

        TextBox tB = (TextBox)sender;
        int Itemrow = -1;
        if (tB != null)
        {
            Itemrow = Grid.GetRow(tB);
        }

        dataObj = new DataObject(Itemrow); 
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(tB, dataObj, DragDropEffects.Move);

        DragDropInAction = false;

    }
```

But i have no idea how to make the drop actions in the other window

Comment: [This Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TksMljeFaV4) might help.

Comment: No, it not helps. My Drop Target is in diferent WPF Window, So my question is how can i start a Drag action in a Windows and perform the Drop action in other Window

Answer (score 0):

According this link:[WPF Drag and Drop between two window](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2e618697-fee6-4b40-bcee-3b2d28e71d68/wpf-drag-and-drop)

1. Call DragDrop.DoDragDrop(.....) method for the item you want to
   drag. Generally it is done at Mousedown event of that item.
2. Configure the control on which you want to drop by setting its
   AllowDrop property to True.
3. Configure Drop event of the item where item has to be dropped.

[**And Code**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2e618697-fee6-4b40-bcee-3b2d28e71d68/wpf-drag-and-drop)